# How to make the view change without visually using a scrolling bar

Tags: c++, qt

What I am trying to do is this, I have a program and it is filled with images and these images go off-screen so obviously a QScrollBar could be used here. I was wondering if it is possible of instead of having like a visual bar that has to be scrolled you could just like press the Right arrow key or Left arrow key to scroll? Like is there a function I can call in an overridden keyPressEvent that would change the view?

I do have an idea though when I print the pictures I could have an offset so when I press the right or left arrow keys it will add or subtract a number from an integer that way it can be added to the x coordinates in the painting algorithm for printing the images to artificially change the view?

```
private:
    int xOffset;
public:

    void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *e) override
    {
        if(e->key() == Qt::RightArrow)
        {
            ++xOffset;
        }
        if(e->key() == Qt::LeftArrow)
        {
            --xOffset;
        }
}
```

And then in the painting event add the offset to the x's of the images to change the view

```
paint(QPainter *qp)
{
for(int l{0}; l < M_images; ++l)
{
   qp.fillRect(M_x+xOffset, M_y, 50, 50, "Pic.png");
}
}
```

Comment: _"so obviously a QScrollBar could be used here"_ -- the word "obviously" strikes again. No, a QScrollBar (by itself) does not cause anything to scroll. A QScrollBar provides the visual interface that you said you do not want. (Give it a try if you want -- if it works, some of your code should be re-usable for your real end goal.) What other widgets would make your list of candidates to try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to get that behavior is to make your widget the target of a [QScrollArea](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscrollarea.html) widget.  The QScrollArea will handle the keypresses and scrolling/offset-rendering for you, as well as providing scroll bars (if you want them -- if you don't, they aren't mandatory; see the comment near the bottom of the example below)

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QGridLayout>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QScrollArea>
#include <QPushButton>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
   QApplication app(argc, argv);

   QMainWindow * mw = new QMainWindow;
   mw->setWindowTitle("QScrollArea demo -- press arrow keys!");

   QScrollArea * sa = new QScrollArea;
   mw->setCentralWidget(sa);

   QWidget * scrollMe = new QWidget;
   QGridLayout * gl = new QGridLayout(scrollMe);
   for (int row=0; row<99; row++)
   {
      for (int col=0; col<99; col++)
      {
         QPushButton * pb = new QPushButton(QString("%1.%2").arg(row+1).arg(col+1));
         gl->addWidget(pb, row, col);
      }
   }
   sa->setWidget(scrollMe);

   // Comment these two lines out if you want visible scroll bars
   sa->setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
   sa->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);

   mw->resize(500, 500);
   mw->show();

   return app.exec();
}
```